# Proving that $\sum\limits^{\infty}_{n=1}\ln\left(1+\frac{x^2}{n^2}\right)$ converges $\forall x \in ℝ$ to a continuous function

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, uniform-convergence

I have tried proving that the series is uniformly continuous $\forall x \in ℝ$ by showing:

$$\lim_{n\to \infty}{\sup_{x\in[-R;R]}{\ln\left(1+\frac{x^2}{n^2}\right)}} = 0$$

But after I did that, I realized that what I need to prove is actually:

$$\lim_{n\to \infty}{\sup_{x\in[-R;R]} \left\lvert\sum\limits^{\infty}_{k=n+1} \ln\left(1+\frac{x^2}{k^2}\right)\right\rvert} = 0$$

and I do not know how to do that, nor am I sure that this is true.

I have also noted that the derivative of $\ln\left(1+\frac{x^2}{n^2}\right)$ is $\frac{2x}{x^2 + n^2}$, but I don't know how to show the uniform convergence of that series, either.

Edit: It was turned to my attention that $0 \le ln(1+y) \le y$, which means that $$\sum\limits^{\infty}_{n=1}\ln\left(1+\frac{x^2}{n^2}\right) \le \sum\limits^{\infty}_{n=1}\frac{x^2}{n^2} = \frac{\pi x^2}{6}$$

But, while certainly showing that the series converges, how does it help me show that it converges *uniformly*?

Comment: For $y \geqslant 0$, one has $0 \leqslant \ln (1+y) \leqslant y$. That could help here.

Comment: I addressed this in an edit to my question. Thank you for your comment, but could you please clarify how I could show the uniform convergence of the original series, or otherwise prove the continuity of the limit?

Comment: For $x \in [-R,R]$ and arbitrary $n$, we have $$\Biggl\lvert \sum_{k = n+1}^{\infty} \ln \biggl(1 + \frac{x^2}{k^2}\biggr)\Biggr\rvert \leqslant \sum_{k = n+1}^{\infty} \biggl\lvert \ln\biggl(1+\frac{x^2}{k^2}\biggr)\biggr\rvert \leqslant \sum_{k = n+1}^{\infty} \frac{x^2}{k^2} \leqslant \sum_{k = n+1}^{\infty} \frac{R^2}{k^2}.$$

Comment: Thank you very much. I appologise for appearing obtuse, but I still do not see how that proves uniform convergence... I do have a theorem saying that if $$\lim_{n\to \infty}{\sup_{x\in[-R;R]} \left\lvert\sum\limits^{\infty}_{k=n+1} \ln\left(1+\frac{x^2}{k^2}\right)\right\rvert} = 0$$, the series converges uniformly, but I do not see how I may deduce this from what you wrote...

Comment: What do you know about $\sum\limits_{k = n+1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{k^2}$ as a function of $n$?

Comment: As n tends towards infinity, this sum necessarily tends towards 0.

Comment: Do you know the Weierstrass M-test?

Comment: Yes. It says that if there's a convergent sequence $M_n$ which is larger than the series $\forall n \in ℝ$, then the series is uniformly converging. So if I had $$\sum\limits^{\infty}_{n=1}\ln\left(1+\frac{x^2}{n^2}\right) \le \sum\limits^{\infty}_{n=1}\frac{1}{n^2} \le 1 \forall n \ge 1$$ then the series would indeed be uniformly converging. However, what I actually have is $$\sum\limits^{\infty}_{n=1}\ln\left(1+\frac{x^2}{n^2}\right) \le \sum\limits^{\infty}_{n=1}\frac{x^2}{n^2}$$ where $\sum\limits^{\infty}_{n=1}\frac{x^2}{n^2}$ does not converge. Am I making a mistake somewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach can be completed by noting that
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=n+1}^\infty\log\left(1+\frac{x^2}{k^2}\right)
&=\sum_{k=n+1}^\infty\frac1{k^2}\log\left(\left(1+\frac{x^2}{k^2}\right)^{k^2}\right)\\
&\le x^2\sum_{k=n+1}^\infty\frac1{k^2}\\\\
&\le x^2\sum_{k=n+1}^\infty\frac1{k^2-k}\\[9pt]
&=\frac{x^2}n
\end{align}
$$

Comment: Thank you very much. But on the second line, shouldn't it be just $x^2$, instead of $e^x^2$, considering we're taking the log? Of course what you're saying is true in either case.

Comment: Yes, thanks. It's fixed.

Answer (score 3):

This is an overkill, but the theory of Weierstrass products (starting from the Mittag-Leffler theorem) grants that
$$\forall x\neq 0,\qquad  \frac{\sinh(\pi x)}{\pi x} = \prod_{n\geq 1}\left(1+\frac{x^2}{n^2}\right) $$
holds pointwise *and* uniformly over any compact subset of $\mathbb{C}$, hence
$$\forall x\neq 0,\qquad \sum_{n\geq 1}\log\left(1+\frac{x^2}{n^2}\right)=\log\left(\frac{\sinh (\pi x)}{\pi x}\right)$$
does the same over $\mathbb{R}$, once we re-define $\frac{\sinh(\pi x)}{\pi x}$ at $x=0$ as $1$ (i.e. we remove the removable discontinuity). Then the RHS is clearly continuous.

Comment: Thank you very much! Do you happen to have a source for this expansion?

Comment: @Montgomery: I recommend https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_factorization_theorem for a start, then  www.springer.com/gp/book/9783319413440 .

Comment: In any case, thank you for a very insightful answer!